# Access the child state from the parent after click event from the parent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to access the child state from the parent after triggering a click event in the parent ?

I am using a modal component that's why the event is not triggering from the child component.

```
const Parent = () => {
    ...
    return (
        <Modal 
            saveHandler={ () => { 
                 // Get child state here to do some stuff with
            }} ... >
            <Child ... />
        </Modal>
    )
}


const Child = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);
    ...
}
```

Comment: It's better to lift the state up to the parent and pass `state` and `dispatch` down as props to the child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of Ref with `useImperativeHandle` to allow parent to access child state

```
const Parent = () => {
    const childRef = useRef(null);
    ...
    return (
            <Modal 
                    saveHandler={ () => { 
                        // Get child state here to do some stuff with
                        console.log(childRef.current.state);
                    }} ... >

                    <Child ref={childRef} ... />
            </Modal>
    )
}


const Child = (props, ref) => {

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
       state
    }), [state])
    ...
}

export default forwardRef(Child);
```

Although you can do what you want using the above code, its recommended that you lift the state up to the parent component and pass it as props to child

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);
    ...
    return (
            <Modal 
                    saveHandler={ () => { 
                        // Get child state here to do some stuff with
                        console.log(state);
                    }} ... >

                    <Child state={state} dispatch={dispatch} ... />
            </Modal>
    )
}


const Child = ({state, dispatch}) => {

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the child to pass the click event you can easily transfer data from the child to parent like so...

```
const dispatch = (stateOfChild) => {
  // do something
}
 return (
   <Modal 
     <Child propsName = {stateOfChild => dispatch(stateOfChild)} />
   </Modal>
  )
```

And in the child

```
 const Child = () => {
 return (
   <div
     onClick= {() => props.propsName(stateOfChild)} ></div>
  )     
 }
```